# Entity framework using ThenInclude - exclude certain columns from linked entities

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

I have a query to return a `Configuration` that looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult Configurations(int id)
    {
        var myConfiguration = dbContext.MyEntity
                                                    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                                                    .Include(e => e.Group)
                                                    .ThenInclude(g => g.Configuration)
                                                    .ThenInclude(c => c.ConfigurationChildren)
                                                    .ThenInclude(cc => cc.ConfigurationGrandchildren)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                                                    .Group?
                                                    .Configuration;

       return Json(myConfiguration);
    }
```

The `Configuration` has a `Client` property that I don't want to include in the returned Json, and the `ConfigurationGrandchildren` each have a `Client` property that I don't want to include. How do I exclude them?

Comment: You can't exclude populating entity navigation properties by EF Core navigation property fix-up, because they are part of the model invariants that EF Core must maintain. But you can exclude anything from serialization using the control provided by the corresponding serializer. Or not use entities for serialization, but projected DTOs. See [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization) section of EF Core documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Stoev. Do you have an example of how I could achieve that for my case?

Comment: Not beautiful on modelling folder

.ThenInclude(entity => new EntitlyDto{  /*map the required properties here like Property1 = entity.Property */ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add [JsonIgnore] above the Client property.

### Configuration.cs

```
public class Configuration
{
     [JsonIgnore]
     public string Client { get; set; }

}
```